# PlaceRequest with parameters to Popup Presenter

Tags: gwt, gwt-platform

I trying to pass a parameter in the placerequest to a presenter that will be a popup, but, the i receive empty parameters in the popup presenter.. am i forgot anything?

AddProjetoPresenter

```
public class AddProjetoPresenter extends Presenter<AddProjetoPresenter.AddProjetoView, AddProjetoPresenter.AddProjetoProxy>
    {
    @ProxyCodeSplit
    @NameToken(NameTokens.addproj)
    public interface AddProjetoProxy extends ProxyPlace<AddProjetoPresenter>
    {
    }

    public interface AddProjetoView extends View
    {
        HasValue<String> getNome();

        HasValue<Date> getDtInicio();

        HasValue<Date> getDtFim();

        HasClickHandlers getAddRequisitos();

        HasClickHandlers getAddStakeholders();

        HasClickHandlers getBtCancelar();

        HasClickHandlers getBtSalvar();
    }

    private final DispatchAsync dispatch;
    private final PlaceManager placeManager;
    private Projeto projeto;

    @Inject
    public AddProjetoPresenter(final EventBus eventBus, final AddProjetoView view, final AddProjetoProxy proxy, final DispatchAsync dispatch,
            final PlaceManager placeManager)
    {
        super(eventBus, view, proxy);
        this.dispatch = dispatch;
        this.placeManager = placeManager;
    }

    @Override
    protected void revealInParent()
    {
        RevealContentEvent.fire(this, MainPresenter.TYPE_SetMainContent, this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBind()
    {
        super.onBind();

        getView().getBtSalvar().addClickHandler(new ClickHandler()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event)
            {

            }
        });

        getView().getAddRequisitos().addClickHandler(new ClickHandler()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event)
            {
                PlaceRequest pr = new PlaceRequest(NameTokens.addreq);
                pr.with("oi", "oiiiii"); // HERE
                placeManager.revealPlace(pr, false);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

AddRequisitoPresenter

```
public class AddRequisitoPresenter extends Presenter<AddRequisitoPresenter.AddRequisitoView, AddRequisitoPresenter.AddRequisitoProxy>
{

    @ProxyCodeSplit
    @NameToken(NameTokens.addreq)
    public interface AddRequisitoProxy extends ProxyPlace<AddRequisitoPresenter>
    {

    }

    public interface AddRequisitoView extends PopupView
    {
        DialogBox getDialog();
    }

    private final DispatchAsync dispatcher;
    private Projeto projeto;

    @Inject
    public AddRequisitoPresenter(final EventBus eventBus, final AddRequisitoView view, final AddRequisitoProxy proxy, final DispatchAsync dispatcher)
    {
        super(eventBus, view, proxy);
        this.dispatcher = dispatcher;
    }

    @Override
    public void prepareFromRequest(PlaceRequest request)
    {
        super.prepareFromRequest(request);
        getView().getDialog().setText(request.getParameterNames().size() + ""); //SIZE IS ZERO!!
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBind()
    {
        super.onBind();
    }

    @Override
    protected void revealInParent()
    {
        RevealRootPopupContentEvent.fire(this, this);
    }
}
```

I think ai doing something wrong...

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understood in the [wiki](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-platform/wiki/GettingStarted?tm=6#Dialog_box_and_popup_panels), a popup can't be a place, and it needs a parent presenter.

I see two obvious problems here :

- Your second presenter (the popup) should implement PresenterWidget, not Presenter
- You can't display a popup by calling placeManager.revealPlace(), because a popup is not a place. Instead, you have to apply one of the two methods explained in the [wiki](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-platform/wiki/GettingStarted?tm=6#Dialog_box_and_popup_panels) (addToPopupSlot() or RevealRootPopupContentEvent.fire(), both called from the parent).

Comment: I understand.. but, with RevealRootPopupContentEvent.fire(), how can i pass parameters?

Comment: actually, my code work, I just replace PlaceRequest pr = new PlaceRequest(NameTokens.addreq); pr.with("oi", "oiiiii"); by PlaceRequest pr = new PlaceRequest(NameTokens.addreq).with("oi", "oiiiii"); and it work very good :P but, if you know a way to pass parameter to a presenter widget...

Comment: Simply have the parent presenter keep a reference on the child, and make the parent call a setter on the child before it fires the RevealRootPopupContentEvent.